# How to write recieved values by POST method in a CSV file

Tags: perl, csv

I want to create a CSV file by accepting ip1 to ip10 values which are sent by POST method from a HTML file. test.cgi file contains the perl code.  I have tried to write a code as following.  Please help me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict; 
use warnings;

$ip1 = $query->param("ip1");
$ip2 = $query->param("ip2");
$ip3 = $query->param("ip3");
$ip4 = $query->param("ip4");
$ip5 = $query->param("ip5");
$ip6 = $query->param("ip6");
$ip7 = $query->param("ip7");
$ip8 = $query->param("ip8");
$ip9 = $query->param("ip9");
$ip10 = $query->param("ip10");

$ie1 = $query->param("ie1");
$ie2 = $query->param("ie2");
$ie3 = $query->param("ie3");
$ie4 = $query->param("ie4");
$ie5 = $query->param("ie5");
$ie6 = $query->param("ie6");
$ie7 = $query->param("ie7");
$ie8 = $query->param("ie8");
$ie9 = $query->param("ie9");
$ie10 = $query->param("ie10");


open(my $fh, ">", "test.csv")or die "$!";
print $fh ",zone A,zone B,zone C,zone D,zone E,zone F,zone G,zone H,zone I,zone j\n";
print $fh "IP,$ip1,$ip2,$ip3,$ip4,$ip5,$ip6,$ip7,$ip8,$ip9,$ip10\n";
print $fh "IE,$ie1,$ie2,$ie3,$ie4,$ie5,$ie6,$ie7,$ie8,$ie9,$ie10\n";
close $fh;`
```

If suppose by post method recieved values for ip are 1 to 10 and for ie are 11 to 20 then My expected output in CSV file is look like:

```
,zone A,zone B,zone C,zone D,zone E,zone F,zone G,zone H,zone I,zone j

IP,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

IE,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: We can't help without more detail as to what problem you're having.

Comment: when i remove all the scalars from the code and try to print a simple text it works perfectly, but the problem is when I'm trying to print values received from a html file by post method it doesn't affects the content of CSV file. or maybe i dont know the correct syntax to print a scalar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked in your web server error log? It looks to me like this program won't even compile. It is full of undeclared variables. To get it to even compile, you would need to change it to something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $query = CGI->new;

my $ip1 = $query->param("ip1");
my $ip2 = $query->param("ip2");
my $ip3 = $query->param("ip3");
my $ip4 = $query->param("ip4");
my $ip5 = $query->param("ip5");
my $ip6 = $query->param("ip6");
my $ip7 = $query->param("ip7");
my $ip8 = $query->param("ip8");
my $ip9 = $query->param("ip9");
my $ip10 = $query->param("ip10");

my $ie1 = $query->param("ie1");
my $ie2 = $query->param("ie2");
my $ie3 = $query->param("ie3");
my $ie4 = $query->param("ie4");
my $ie5 = $query->param("ie5");
my $ie6 = $query->param("ie6");
my $ie7 = $query->param("ie7");
my $ie8 = $query->param("ie8");
my $ie9 = $query->param("ie9");
my $ie10 = $query->param("ie10");


open(my $fh, ">", "test.csv")or die "$!";
print $fh ",zone A,zone B,zone C,zone D,zone E,zone F,zone G,zone H,zone I,zone j\n";
print $fh "IP,$ip1,$ip2,$ip3,$ip4,$ip5,$ip6,$ip7,$ip8,$ip9,$ip10\n";
print $fh "IE,$ie1,$ie2,$ie3,$ie4,$ie5,$ie6,$ie7,$ie8,$ie9,$ie10\n";
close $fh;
```

But please don't do that. That's very wasteful of variables. Don't you know there's a global variable shortage? :-)

When you see repetitive code like yours, you should consider using an array or hash to simplify it. I'd write your code something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw(param header);
use strict;
use warnings;

my (@ip, @ie);

for (1 .. 10) {
  push @ip, param("ip$_");
  push @ie, param("ie$_");
}

# You'll need to ensure that test.csv is somewhere that your CGI program
# has permission to write files.
open(my $fh, '>', 'test.csv')or die $!;
print $fh ',', join(',', map { "zone $_" } 'A' .. 'J'), "\n";
print $fh 'IP,', join(',', @ip), "\n";
print $fh 'IE,', join(',', @ie), "\n";
close $fh;

# You'll probably want to do something more interesting here too.
print header('text/plain');
print 'File created';
```

Comment: Dave's codes are very clean and elegant, great job cleaning up the repetitiveness.

Comment: It works, thank you Dave Cross and i am sorry it was my first experience with perl.

Comment: Nothing to apologise for. We all had to start somewhere :-) Hopefully you'll have learned something about debugging problems like this (use `perl -c` to check the syntax of your program, check the web log for errors).

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'll definitely follow your advise..:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$ip1 = param('ip1');
```

If this does not work, then also post the HTML you are trying.

Comment: This seems like clutching at straws to me. There is no reason to believe that `$ip1 = param('ip1')` is going to act in any way differently to the existing `$ip1 = $query->param("ip1")`. Am I missing something/